# Conditional formatting depending on data from a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to create a rule that writes `"100%"` in column A whenever I write `"end"` in column B.
So it would be something like this:

```
[]     X
100%   end
[]     Y
```

The brackets represent an empty cell.

I've tried:

```
IF(B1:B3="end",100%,"")
```

but I would like to leave the cells on column A empty, with no data or formulas, if the respective cell in column B doesn't contain "end".

So I've thought about adding a new rule with conditional formatting but it's not working. Any solutions?

Comment: Congratulations! You have reached the limits of Excel. In order to expand these limits, you need VBA.  https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+vba+in+excel

Comment: An Excel formula can only change the value of the cell it resides in, so the formulas would have to be present in those cells.  Why does it matter if the cells have formulas (that you can't see)?

Comment: ...but I think the formula you had intended was:  (in Cell A1:  `=IF(B1="end","100%","")` ...and then copy and paste to other cells in column A and the formula will automatically adjust to be looking at the cell in column B that's *next* to it.   *Conditional Formatting* on the other hand *can* affect any cells you want, but it's **formatting only**.  So you could make the cell Green with nothing in it, but you can't make it say "100%" without having "something" in the cell all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit:

**You *can* get a value to show in a cell based on the value of another cell, without having anything* in the cell, *and* without VBA:**

<sup><sub>*kinda</sub></sup>

[image: example3]

> **Using cells `I2:J9` as an example, the steps are:**
>
> 1. Click `I2`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to open the *Format Cells* dialog.
> 2. On the *Number* tab, click `Custom`, then in the *Type* box enter: **`;;;`** and click <sub><sup><kbd>OK</kbd></sup></sub>.
> 3. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to add new Conditional Format and choose *Use a formula to determine which
>      cells to format*.
> 4. In the *Format values where...* box, enter: **`=J2="end"`** (If Excel adds `$`'s, remove them), then click <kbd>Format...</kbd>
> 5. On the *Number* tab, click `Custom`, then in the *Type* box enter: **`;;;"100%"`** . (Optionally set a color, font, etc.) then hit <sub><sup><kbd>ENTER</kbd></sup></sub> 3 times to return to the
>      worksheet.
> 6. Click `I2`, hit your <sub><sup><kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd></sup></sub> once and then hit <sub><sup><kbd>ENTER</kbd></sup></sub>.  <sup>(* Fine, I
>      confess: the cell isn't *totally* empty.)</sup>
> 7. Click `I2` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to Copy.
> 8. Select `I2:J9` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then hit
>      <sub><sup><kbd>ENTER</kbd></sup></sub> to Paste Formats.

Now when you type `end` into any of `J2:J9`, the corresponding cell in column `I` will display `100%`.

You can also repeat this process to add additional conditions to the same cells if needed.

---

### Original Answer: <sub><sup>(Alternative Solutions)</sup></sub>

<sup>Sometimes I get stuck spending too much time on a question about a very minor issue.  This is one of those times.</sup>  :)

Thinking further about your question, I suspect you might not have meant you need the *"cells on column A empty, with no data or formulas"*, but perhaps you mean you want the cells to ***"appear empty"***.

---

### Example:

[image: screenshot example]

These cells do *appear* empty, unless you to click on the cell and then look at the formula bar:

[image: ex1] [image: ex2]

...but the formula bar can be hidden too:

[image: hide formula bar]

Answer (score 1):

Can be achieved with CF but rather nastily. You would need to fill ColumnA first, say with `1`s - but can be hidden by (standard) formatting the text to match the background colour (ie usually white).

Then clear any CF from and select ColumnA, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=B1="end"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select Black (probably) font and Custom Number format of:

```
00%
```

<kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

If your blank cells *must* remain blank in reality rather than appearance then CF alone is not a solution for you.